# In python I have a print statement after my else: yet it does not seem to actually print it after running the code

Tags: python

```
pin1 = int(input("Please set a pin: "))
print("Welcome to Satan's Soul Bank, Enter ya pin!")
attempt = int(input("Please enter your pin number first"))

if attempt == pin1:
    print("Select operation.")
    print("1.Deposit Souls")
    print("2.Withdraw Souls")
    print("3.Check Soul balance")
    choice = int(input("Enter choice(1/2/3):"))
elif attempt != pin1:
              for i in range(2):
                  attempt = int(input("Invalid Attempt Please enter your pin 
number again"))
else:
    print ("Card Swallowed Contact SATAN")
```

The code itself works apart from the print statement after the else: it seems to not recognize it and just misses it, basically I need it to print that the card has been swallowed after 3 times however when i put it into the elif area it just prints it each time I get the pin wrong so is there any other way to get around that resulting in it printing that the card has been swallowed after the 3rd time

Comment: your `elif` covers every instance that doesn't meet your `if` condition, so you'll never enter the `elif`

Comment: You never reach the `else`. Apart from the two conditions, what else could it be ? :)

Comment: The conditions for your `else` to be executed will never happen. If `attempt==pin1` then the `if` block will be run. If `attempt!=pin1` then the `elif` block will be run. If _neither of those happens_ (i.e. never), then the `else` block will be run.

Comment: You may find this question helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other answers, the `elif` block covers the condition not satisfied by `if` block. To make sure that you print the statement in `else` block, you can make use of a `flag` variable which will be set to `false` before maximum wrong attempts. Once the **maximum attempts** is reached, set the `flag` to `true`.

If the `flag` is set to `true`, `print` 'card swallowed. Contact satan...'

Answer (score 1):

You need to restructure your code to get what you want.

```
pin1 = int(input("Please set a pin: "))
print("Welcome to Satan's Soul Bank, Enter ya pin!")

correct_pin = False

for i in range(3):
    attempt = int(input("Please enter your pin number first"))
    if attempt == pin1:
        correct_pin = True
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid PIN. {} attempts remain.".format(2 - i))

if correct_pin:
    print("Select operation.")
    print("1.Deposit Souls")
    print("2.Withdraw Souls")
    print("3.Check Soul balance")
    choice = int(input("Enter choice(1/2/3):"))
else:
    print ("Card Swallowed Contact SATAN")
```

We loop 3 times, exiting if the user gets the correct pin, and only offer further options if the pin was correct.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have

```
if attempt == pin1:
    ...
elif attempt != pin1:
   ...
```

Since one of the conditions always holds (either `attempt` equals `pin1` or not), the program will never arrive to the `else` part.

Answer (score 0):

The 'else' block in your code only runs if the `if` and the `elif` blocks are **both** false.  The only way this could happen is if `(attempt == pin1)` is false **and** `(attempt != pin1)` is false.

As you can see this is impossible because either they are equal or they're not - it can't be neither.  This is why `print ("Card Swallowed Contact SATAN")` will never run.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, you wanted the program to behave some thing like the following:

```
pin1 = int(input("Please set a pin: "))
print("Welcome to Satan's Soul Bank, Enter ya pin!")
attempt = int(input("Please enter your pin number first"))

if attempt == pin1:
    print("Select operation.")
    print("1.Deposit Souls")
    print("2.Withdraw Souls")
    print("3.Check Soul balance")
    choice = int(input("Enter choice(1/2/3):"))
elif attempt != pin1:
            for i in range(2):
                attempt = int(input("Invalid Attempt Please enter your pin number again"))
            print ("Card Swallowed Contact SATAN")
```

After two incorrect attempt, you wanted to tell the user to contact SA**

Comment: Thank you! Just adding more characters to post this as well ;)

Comment: Except that this code will just ask thrice to enter PIN again, without checking if the entered PIN is correct, then produce the SATAN message. Clearly not what was intended.